# SQLite WP8 DateTime Issue 1/1/0001

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am having a strange issue.  I am creating a WP8 app with SQLite.  I have a table that has 3 fields,

1. RowID (PK int)
2. Name (NVARCHAR)
3. RecordDate (DATETIME)

There are records in the database for sure, I can see them using SQLite Expert, and their datatypes.
When I do a query on the table all the records show up in my ListBox except the ALL the RecordDate fields are displaying 1/1/0001.  Really strange.  I have used this same process in other apps I have written but I cant figure it out.  Can anyone help?

Thanks Much

Edit:

```
var query = db.Table<MyTable>().OrderByDescending(c => c.RecordDate);
```

In the database itself the date looks like this `2013-06-02 19:31:00`.

Comment: post the query too, so that it could be figured out.

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `RecordDate` column?

Comment: Hi, The query is: var query = db.Table<MyTable>().OrderByDescending(c => c.RecordDate);  In the database itself the date looks like this 2013-06-02 19:31:00